# chipkit max32 Lost sync with device, restarting

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the rosserial tutorial "hello world" on a chipkit max 32. I can compile and upload to program to the max32. when I run
"r**osrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB1",**
it returns
**ROS Serial Python Node**
**Connected on /dev/ttyUSB1 at 57600 baud**
then after several seconds it returns
**[ERROR] Lost sync with device, restarting....**
when I first start the python node the tx light blinks and every time the node tries to connect.
I have read other posts, but non of them seem to answer or fix the issue. The max 32 is almost identical to the arduino due but it runs on a pic controller.
I am using the latest mpide 23. I am not sure how to get it to connect and work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55559/chipkit-max32-lost-sync-with-device,-restarting.../) by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2013-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Groovy or Fuerte? The release into Groovy is currently broken (but will hopefully be fixed very soon, there is quite a bit of activity on github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on 2013-02-19**:
Yes I am using groovy.

**Comment by [packrat](https://answers.ros.org/users/3685/packrat/) on 2013-03-11**:
has rosserial been fixed yet? I tried installing it from source but not luck, it still says [ERROR] Lost sync with device, restarting....